# Multiple Rails apps read single database/table of another Rails app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I have a web app and API for the app configured and completed, but work is now requesting more apps. The apps are web-heavy with a light API for mobile functionality. A monolithic apps seems out of the question, so I decided to make each one individually. Each app will have their own layout, database, and API. However, the one thing I want to share among all apps is the users' password, api token, and firebase messaging token. A separate app will be created just for authentication with **IDnumber**, **password**, **api token**, and **fcm token**. 4 simple fields. This single app will be the only one doing any writing to it's DB and this single table.

Creating requests to the auth app to verify every request to each API seems inefficient, so I was wondering if there was a way for the apps to tap into the auth database and verify tokens and passwords directly. There would be no joining of tables cross-apps and no cross-app creation/updating/deletion. Problems with keeping models and schemas synced make sense, but would read-only custom queries eliminate those issues?

Comment: What issues are you referring to in your question? What do you mean by "keeping models and schema synced"?

Answer (score 0):

Integration at DB level is messy - any change would need to be done on every application using it, and the security is a concerns too.

The typical solution for your problem (having several application share a unique authentication source) is [OAuth](https://oauth.net/2/) - a way for the multiple apps to delegate authentication to your "Auth App". This is well supported by frameworks such as [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).